# Read specific sheets from an excel file list

Tags: r, excel, spreadsheet, data-import

I need to read specific sheets from a list of excel files.
I have >500 excel files, `".xls"` and `".xlsx"`.
Each file can have different sheets, but I just want to read each sheets containing a specific expresion, like `pattern = "^Abc"`, and not all files have sheets with this pattern.
I've created a code to read one file, but when I try to translate to multiple files, allways returns an error.

```
# example with 3rd file
# 2 sheets have the pattern

list_excels <- list.files(path = "path_to_folder", pattern = ".xls*"
sheet_names <- excel_sheets(list_excels[[3]])
list_sheets <- lapply(excel_sheets(list_excels[[3]]), read_excel, path = list_excels[[3]])
names(list_sheets) <- sheet_names
do.call("rbind", list_sheets[grepl(pattern = "^Abc", sheet names)])
```

But when I try to code for read multiple excels files, I have an error or something in the loop that slows a lot the computation.

There are some examples

This is a loop that doesn't return an error, but takes 30 seconds at least for each element of the list, I've never waited to finishing .

```
for (i in seq_along(list_excels)) { 
sheet_names <- excel_sheets(list_excels[[i]]) 
list_sheets <- lapply(excel_sheets(list_excels[[i]]), read_excel, path = list_excels[[i]]) 
names(list_sheets) <- sheet_names[i] list_sheets[grepl(pattern = "^Abc", sheet_names)]
}
```

In this loop is missing the final part, the merging sheets with this code

```
list_sheets[grepl(pattern = "^Abc", sheet_names)]
```

I've tried to sum the rows of each sheet and store it in an vector, but I think that the loop is broken when there is a sheet that doesn't have the pattern.

```
x <- c()
for(i in seq_along(list_excels)) {
  x[i] <- nrow(do.call("rbind",
                       lapply(excel_sheets(list_excels[[i]]),
                              read_excel,
                              path = list_excels[[i]])[grepl(pattern = "^Abc",
                                                          excel_sheets(list_excels[[i]]))]))
```

Also with `purrr` library, trying to read all, the same result with first loop example.

```
list_test <- list()
for(i in seq_along(list_excels)) {
  list_test[[i]] <- excel_sheets(list_excels[[i]]) %>%
                              set_names() %>%
                              map(read_excel, path = list_excels[[i]])
}
```

Last example, that works with one excel file, but not with multiple. Just reading named sheet.

```
# One file works
    data.frame(readWorksheetFromFile(list_excels[[1]], sheet = "Abc"))
#Multiple file returns an error
for(i in seq_along(list_excels)) {
  data.frame(readWorksheetFromFile(list_excels[[i]], sheet = "Abc"))
#Returns the following error
#Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..1)
```

Some one could help me?

Comment: Can you show your attempt at the loop? Also, error messages are usually informative. Don't say you get "an error", show the error and we can help you understand and fix it.

Comment: I think the error comes from the excel files that doesn't have sheets with `pattern = "^Abc"`